# Laravel: resource not found exception

Tags: laravel-5

Say you have a simple resource route like this:

```
Route::resource('overview', 'OverviewController');
```

And hit routes which you know don't exist. For example:

```
/overview/sdflkjdsflkjsd  
/overview/sdflkjdsflkjsd/edit
```

Which in my case throws `Trying to get property of non-object` error from my view (as no resource is found)

I looked into adding 'Regular Expression Parameter Constraints' from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing), but it looks like these are not available for resource routes either (plus don't really fix the problem).

I'm looking for a way to throw a single exception for this kind of thing, which I can then handle once, rather than add logic to each action (or at least the `show` and `edit` actions).. if possible.

**EDIT** After looking around github, I found the exception in the Symphony repo [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2aeaa22e3171b5e1f10f2cc2a7ff7f6608b65f9d/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Exception/ResourceNotFoundException.php).  Is there a way I can hook into it?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're getting a `Trying to get property of non-object` error, I assume you're fetching the resource via `YourModel::find();`

I'd suggest you use `YourModel::findOrFail()` instead. Then, you'd be getting a specific type of exception called `ModelNotFoundException`. Just register an error handler for this.

For instance,

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
});
```

**UPDATE:** This would actually go into render() method inside the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file in Laravel 5.1, and of course the code would utilize the passed $e parameter instead.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
   {
        return \Response::make('Not Found', 404);
   }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, findOrFail is a great answer to this and can be done on one neat line.  However it doesn't work in my situation as I am actually querying a relation like this: `$overview = $event->overviews->find($id)`.  I'm finding a lot of eloquent model functionality doesn't exist for eloquent collections (another useful one missing is 'whereNotNull').

Comment: You can still use it. Just call it on the relationship query instead of the collection. In fact, you could include any where clause you want. So it would be `$event->overviews()->whereNotNull('fieldName')->firstOrFail();`  Let me explain it in this way. If you call the overviews relationship as a property, it fetches them all as a collection and you get whatever the collection class offers you. However, if you call it as a method, then you're referring to the query builder.